# Why the lastIndexOf function in JSP is not giving exact index value for black slash of a string?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to locate where in the string a specifed value occurs.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var pattern = "\\";
    var str = "C:\filepath\contactlist.txt";
    var n = str.lastIndexOf(pattern)+1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The excepted value is 12 but it is giving 0,because lastIndexOf fuction returns -1. When I replaced the single slash in str variable with double slash(**"C:\filepath\contactlist.txt"**) it was giving 12 as excepted.

why the **lastIndexOf** function is giving -1 when I use single backward slash in str ?

Am I using the double backward slash **pattern** correctly to search for the single backward slash in **str**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash character is used in strings to escape string metacharacters, like quotes or the backslash itself, as well as for the five special "control" characters (n, r, f, t, and b).  When used before any other character, the backslash is ignored. Thus, when you build that string with only single backslashes, the resulting *actual* string value won't include any backslashes.